# Search Terminal Output

Tags: linux, search, ubuntu, terminal, gnome

Using a default terminal and bash, there is no functionality to search the standard output of commands.

One can gain such functionality using other tools, like emacs shell or screen, but I am wondering why such a useful feature is missing, I do remember a simple C-F used to work in terminals.

Is there a way to make the Gnome terminal app support output search? or is there a better terminal app that support searching output natively?

Comment: Does piping the command into `less` not give you what you desire? You can search text in `less` and many other pagers. Also, shouldn't this be on super user?

Comment: Yes, `less` is good for one command output, but I often do multiple commands and come back later with the need to search all output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try script(1). On login just call script and you can then search through the typescript file it generates. It's not a single keystroke like emacs shell and it is buffered, but it might be better than nothing.

Comment: Can you search script while `script` is running?  I tried and couldn't...

Answer (score 24):

Try <kbd>Ctr</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd>. This works on Ubuntu terminal and Terminator

Comment: Same hotkey in gnome-terminal.

Comment: on a Mac zsh terminal: command key + F will search through out all terminar output

Answer (score 1):

Don't know `gnome-terminal` but `urxvt` does that by typing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd>. It should be in your repositories, lookup the package [`rxvt-unicode`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=names&keywords=rxvt-unicode).

Answer (score 1):

Using `xterm`, you can log everything the terminal displays to a file. Then you can open that file in an editor or `less`.

Answer (score 1):

In `screen` you can enter `copy` mode and do searches on output. You can also do logging of output to a file and search it any way you normally would (`grep`, `less`, etc.).